# How to send the order of a table sorted by JQuery UI via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I order the rows of a table via JQuery UI as ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f2hk28h/))

```
<table id="sort" class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Permanent ID</th><th class="index">Sorted</th><th>Rest of the row</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>63</th><td class="index"></td><td>something</td></tr>
        <tr><th>65</th><td class="index"></td><td>test</td></tr>
        <tr><th>11</th><td class="index"></td><td>more text</td></tr>
        <tr><th>333</th><td class="index"></td><td>other stuff</td></tr>
        <tr><th>2</th><td class="index"></td><td>something text</td></tr>
    </tbody>
```

and JS

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
},
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
        });
    };

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
```

After each drag and drop, the second column (`class="index"`) is updated by the new order. How can I get this new row number and send it via AJAX to the server?

In fact, I need to send an array of `"Permanent ID"="Sorted"` via AJAX after each drag and drop action.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to find `index` for a specified element.
Please try this:

```
$('#getIndex').click(function(){
   $('tbody tr').each(function(){
     if($(this).find('th').html()=='333'){
        alert($(this).find('.index').html());
        //var index=$(this).find('.index').html();
        $.ajax({
           //code
        });
     }
   });
});
```

You can get index for `element` by "extracting" the information from `.index` class.

Here is an example which display index for element with `id=333`.

```js
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
},
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
        });
    };

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
$('#getIndex').click(function(){
    $('tbody tr').each(function(){
      if($(this).find('th').html()=='333'){
         alert($(this).find('.index').html());
      }
    });
});
$('#getArray').click(function(){
    var arr=[];
    $('tbody tr').each(function(){
         arr.push($(this).find('th').text());
    });
    console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="sort" class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Permanent ID</th><th class="index">Sorted</th><th>Rest of the row</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>63</th><td class="index"></td><td>something</td></tr>
        <tr><th>65</th><td class="index"></td><td>test</td></tr>
        <tr><th>11</th><td class="index"></td><td>more text</td></tr>
        <tr><th>333</th><td class="index"></td><td>other stuff</td></tr>
        <tr><th>2</th><td class="index"></td><td>something text</td></tr>
    </tbody>
 <br>
  <br>
 Get index for row with id=333;
 <button id="getIndex">
 Get Index
 </button>
 <button id="getArray">
    Get Array
 </button>
  <br>
   <br>
```